# consume wcf service on separate thread

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf

I have win form which represents simple wcf client app. This client consumes wcf service over http.

Inside form there is `loadingLabel.Text` property where I want to display loading ... text. When wcf service returns data other property `labelAllBooksNr.Text` should be populated.

Service will return integer in allBooksNumber property.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    int allBooksNumber = BookAgent.CountAllBooks();        
 }
```

Since I do not have any experience in using threads I'm asking to someone provide the best pattern I should follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the  best pattern you  can use is  the BackgroundWorker  as Executes an operation on a separate thread and  offers many methods

*from  MSDN*

> *When you want a responsive UI and you are faced with long delays
>   associated with such operations, the BackgroundWorker class provides a
>   convenient solution.*

```
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1

  {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int allBooksNumber = BookAgent.CountAllBooks();
        e.Result = allBooksNumber;  
    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
         label1.Text = "Loading....";
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = e.Result.ToString;  
    }
}
```

}'

Hope this help